# logic operators ||

Tags: c

```
  if ( (code == S || M || L || N || P || K ||R || C || U || W || O) )
    {
       return T;
    }
```

Am I using the or operator correctly? I was intending for to be either one of those Character but I'm not sure if I am correctly using the operator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that is not valid. Firstly, each one would have to be in single quotes, and secondly, you must explicitly compare with each character- that is, `if(code == 'S' || code == 'M' ...)`.

If you're checking this many conditions, it's time to get an array and use a loop.

Answer (score 9):

You would need to write:

```
code == 'S' || code == 'M' || code == 'L', etc.
```

But you could also do:

```
if(strchr("SMLNPKJRCUWO", code) != NULL) (or != 0, if you don't have NULL defined)
{}
```

`strchr` says "Is a char in a string?  If so, give me a pointer to where it is.  If not, then return NULL" (which is just a fancy way of saying zero).

To use strchr, you will probably need to have `#include <string.h>` at the top of your source file.

Answer (score 1):

No, you should write -

```
if ( (code == 'S') ||(code == 'M') ||(code == 'L') /*....*/)
```

Answer (score 0):

No you do not. `||` is the logical or operation, and the C-compiler will interpret it like this:

```
if ( (code == 'S' || 'M' != 0 || 'L' != 0 || 'N' != 0 || 'P' != 0 || 'K' != 0 || 'R' != 0 || 'C' != 0 || 'U' != 0 || 'W' != 0 || 'O' != 0) )
```

which I would expect to be the case anyway. I am sure you wanted something less casual-languuage like, but mathematically correct:

```
if ( (code == 'S' || code == 'M' || code == 'L' || code == 'N' || code == 'P' || code == 'K' || code == 'R' || code == 'C' || code == 'U' || code == 'W' || code == 'O') )
```

Maybe you want to consider a `switch`, which would look nicer and clearer.

```
switch(code) {
case 'S':
case 'M':
case 'L':
case 'N':
case 'P':
case 'K':
case 'R':
case 'C':
case 'U':
case 'W':
case 'O':
    return 'T';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No. First off, I'm assuming that `code` is of type char and contains a single character.

If you want to use an if statement, you'd need to write ...

```
if ( (code == 'S' || code == 'M' || code == 'L' || ...)
{
   return 'T';
}
```

However, I recommend that you use a switch/case for this.

```
switch(code){
case 'S':
case 'M':
case 'L':
case 'N':
case 'P':
case 'K':
case 'R':
case 'C':
case 'U':
case 'W':
case 'O':
    return 'T';
    break;
case 'V':
    /* Do something else if code == 'V' */
    break;
default:
    /* It's any other value... */
}
```

Normally when using switch/case, you're told to use break after each option, because the options will "fall through". But you can also use this to your advantage if you have multiple options.